# How to deploy laravel into a docker container while there are jobs running

Tags: laravel, docker

We are trying to migrate our laravel setup to use docker. Dockerizing the laravel app was straight forward however we ran into an issue where if do a deployment while scheduled jobs are running they would be killed since the container is destroyed.  Whats the best practice here? Having a separate container to run the laravel scheduler doesnt seem like it would solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Run the scheduled job in a different container so you can scale it independently of the laravel app.
- Run multiple containers of the scheduled job so you can stop some to upgrade them while the old ones will continue processing jobs.
- Docker will send a SIGTERM signal to the container and wait for the container to exit cleanly before issuing SIGKILL (the time between the two signals is configurable, 10 seconds by default). This will allow to finish your current job cleanly (or save a checkpoint to continue later).

The plan is to stop old containers and start new containers gradually so there aren't lost jobs or downtime. If you use an orchestrator like Docker Swarm or Kubernetes, they will handle most of these logistics for you.

Note: the laravel scheduler is based on cron and will fire processes that will be killed by docker. To prevent this have the scheduler add a job to a laravel queue. The queue is a foreground process and it will be given the chance to stop/save cleanly by the SIGTERM that it will receive before being killed.

Comment: Doesnt the laravel scheduler run in the background? In that case the running job would still get killed right?

Comment: @Prem, Yes, you are right, i confused the schedule:run with the queue:work. But still it can work by having the scheduler add a job to the queue. Now the queue is a foreground process and it will be given che chance to stop/save cleanly by the SIGTERM that it will receive before being killed.

Comment: Please see also this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76462520/how-to-handle-sigterm-signal-on-laravel-8-9-10-deploy-with-docker-containers-in/76462521#76462521