# Why some of my laravel queue jobs are executing twice and update balances in database twice?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-queue

I am using laravel 8 for my application and every is working fine except sometimes my queue jobs are running twice which is causing database ledger balance to update twice .

I found out this issue before also but neglected thinking my code might be wrong but yesterday also I encountered same issues.
This issues is not happening with all jobs but in very few like 1-2 jobs in 100 jobs.
I am using database driver for managing jobs.

Here is my code implementation

I using following in my job file

```
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;


    public $retryAfter = 85; 
    public $timeout = 80;
    public $tries = 3;
```

my code is not calling jobs twice I have checked it also I am using supervisor for managing queues and I have attached supervisor config.

I am using below code to dispatch job

```
UpdateDailyLedgerReport::dispatch($this->ledger_id, $this->name, $type, $date, $amount);
```

I have checked my code multiple times but there is no trace of calling jobs twice and the things is sometime while update two ledger balances i.e model with equal amount one model is getting update with correct amount but second model balance is updated twice .

Same issue I have seen with my another job .

Thanks.

Previous my jobs timeout was only 30 sec but I have increased it and still the issues is there.

Just now I have checked and found out following is causing isseus:

SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction (SQL: delete from jobs where id = 10892) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\Database\QueryException(code: 40001): SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction (SQL: delete from jobs where id = 10892) at /var/www/vhosts/poshbooks.in/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:712)

can anyone help me to fix it

Comment: To help debug this I would generate a unique code ([uniqid](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) should be enough) and pass to the job and then write the hash of the processing job in a log. That way you know if the same unique code is being processed then its the scheduler at fault otherwise it's the dispatcher and you can take it from there.

Comment: can you share its implementation to log it ??

Comment: Change your `UpdateDailyLedgerReport` constructor to e.g. `public function __construct($ledgerId, $name, $date, $amount, private string $jobId)` then in your `handle` method do `\Log::debug("Processing ledger job ".$this->jobId)` and dispatch it as `UpdateDailyLedgerReport::dispatch($this->ledger_id, $this->name, $type, $date, $amount, uniqid());`

Comment: thanks , I have added this implementation but don't know when the issue will be replicated .. do you have any idea about it or my database driver for queue is creating the issue?

Comment: I have check old logs and found out that jobs is processing only once but database update it twice :
[2023-09-25 22:08:10][10892] Processing: App\Jobs\UpdateDailyLedgerReport
[2023-09-25 22:08:10][10892] Processed:  App\Jobs\UpdateDailyLedgerReport

Comment: After futther checking I got this error in logs for the issue
[2023-09-25 20:08:10] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction (SQL: delete from `jobs` where `id` = 10892) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 40001): SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction (SQL: delete from `jobs` where `id` = 10892) at /var/www/vhosts/poshbooks.in/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:712)

Comment: Try changing your queue driver to something like Redis. It looks like the job doesn't get deleted from the queue for some reason.

Comment: can i use aws sqs ?? are there any drawbacks of sqs

Comment: The drawback of SQS is that you need to use AWS to use SQS, Redis is more broadly available. If you aready use AWS then SQS is a fine option

Comment: thanks ... I already use aws ... but there are some settings in the sql for delay and other ... what  value should I use?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. The queue worker usually has a timeout and a queue has a "retry_after" value but those are not database specific settings. Which settings are you talking about?

Comment: I am taking about the settings of aws sqs .

Comment: while create a sqs in aws there are certain settings

Comment: mistakenly I wrote sqs as sql

Comment: I've not used SQS personally. I think you will need some careful reading of the AWS and Laravel docs as well as some good testing. From a glance I'd say, set "visibility timeout" to what you need for your "retryAfter" value. Other than that I don't know.

Comment: Your job is locked so no other worker can take it, you are reserving the job for 85s but it the timeout could be more than 85s , so when the queue turns again on your job it found as ready but the transaction of the 1st attempt still running, well I suggest to estimate your job timeout and try to set `afterCommit = 'true'` or use `WithoutOverlapping($this->ledger_id)`  to prevent duplicate queue on the same job

Comment: thanks psylogic but job hardly takes 1 sec to complete but I was facing some issues so I increased it ,..... I will set it to 30 sec but will adding WithoutOverlapping middleware fix the issue or shall i use aws sqs ?

Answer (score 0):

The jobs must be idempotent. Meaning if they execute more than once they should not break your logic. Increment the ledgers without jobs. On deploys it could happen if the sigterm signal is not handled properly.

[How to handle SIGTERM signal on laravel 8,9,10 deploy with docker containers in regards to scheduler and worker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76462520/how-to-handle-sigterm-signal-on-laravel-8-9-10-deploy-with-docker-containers-in)

Comment: thanks but can you explain what should I do in my scenario also why this deadlock issue is coming ... framework should handle it right ?

Comment: SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction (SQL: delete from jobs where id = 10892) {"exception":"[object]  this means that 2 workers picked up the job in parallel and the first to finish it can't remove the job from db. DB queue is for DEVELOPMENT ONLY. Use Sqs from aws or other solution.

Comment: thanks ...
Previously I was using timeout to 5 sec and retry to 7 sec but I have encountered following error so I increased :

App\Jobs\UpdateDailyLedgerReport has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out.

Comment: can you tell me setting for aws sqs for queues which executing very quickly and for queus which takes lot of time like reports whcih takes 10- 15 to generate just as an example.

Comment: max visibility timeout in sqs is 15 minutes if I remember right.

Comment: what value to use for Delivery delay?

Comment: Using SQS fixed the issue .... also setting value to 15 minutes will add a delay of minutes.